# Is it possible to represent a ‘mutual IS-A’ relationship in an entity-relationship diagram?

Tags: database-design, erd, subtypes

Is the following scenario *correct* and why:

- *A* and *B* are two entities
- *B* is-a *A*
- *A* is-a *B*

And what if *A*, *B* were relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In databases, subtyping means that one domain is a subset of another. If A is a subset of B and B is a subset of A, then it means A = B. The same logic applies whether A and B are entity sets or relationship sets. There would be no point distinguishing A and B in an ER model.